# Functional equaliton on continuous function $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-equations

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and suppose that $f(0)=f(1).$ Show that there is a value $x\in [0, 1998/1999]$ satisfying $f(x)=f(x+1/1999)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: examine the sign of the function$$g(x)=f(x+1/1999)-f(x)$$ on that domain and use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Nice hint! +1 :)

Comment: I considered the same function. But how to check that this function changes sign?

Comment: I consider the sum $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{1998}g\left(\dfrac{k}{1999}\right)=f(1)-f(0)=0$. Hence we have the following cases: 1) $x_j=0$ or 2) $x_i>0$ and $x_j<0$ and we use Intermediate value theorem. Right?

Comment: @RaheemNajib Exactly. If any of the $g(k/1999)$ are zero, we are done. If none of them are zero, then your sum says that there must be both positive and negative values for $g$. In that case, the intermediate value theorem says that there is a $y$ somewhere (between a positive and a negative point) with $g(y)=0$.

Comment: @Arthur, Excellent hint! Thank for help! +1